# Modifying the time granularity of a state sequence

Tags: traminer, sequence-analysis

I created a sequence object from my SPELL-formatted data set. The sequence length of the sequence object is 1440 (i.e., 1-min intervals for a day).

Is there any easy way for TraMineR to convert the sequence length from 1440 to 288 (i.e., 5-min intervals), using the status in the first minute of every time interval to represent an individual's status during that 5-min period?

Comment: The title of the question may be confusing. What about changing it to something like: Modifying the time granularity of a state sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply select the corresponding columns. In your case, this should be columns 1, 6, 11, ... You can get the column indices using the "seq" function:

```
column.5min <- seq(from = 1, to = 1440, by=5)
```

Now you can select the column, for instance using:

```
myseq5min <- myseq[, column.5min]
```

Here is an example using the "mvad" data set and selecting the first state of each year.

```
 ## Loading the library
 library(TraMineR)
 data(mvad)
 ## Defining sequence properties
 mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school", "training")
 mvad.lab <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education", "joblessness", "school", "training")
 mvad.shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
 ## The state sequence object.
 mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 17:86, alphabet = mvad.alphabet, states = mvad.shortlab, labels = mvad.lab, xtstep = 6)
 ## Now select the column every year (every twelve monthes)
 mvad.seq.year <- mvad.seq[, seq(from=1, to=70, by=12)]
 seqdplot(mvad.seq.year)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to use the `seqgranularity` function provided by the `TraMineRextras` package.
This function changes the time granularity using different methods, currently either `"first"` state or `"last"` state, but other methods such as choosing the most frequent state in the aggregated spell should be implemented in the future.

For the example above, you would just use

```
mvadg.seq.year <- seqgranularity(mvad.seq, tspan=12, method = "first")
```

`TraMineRextras` should be made available on the CRAN in the near future. In the meantime,  if you have the latest version of R, you can just install it from R-Forge with

```
install.packages("TraMineRextras", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```