# Problem with big Data in TraMineR

Tags: traminer

I would like to analyse the trajectories of patients hospitalized for CVA (cerebrovascular accident) with the package TraMineR.
I have a large dataset with around 25,000 trajectories observed during 365 days.
There are 5 states in my data.
When I try to use the seqdist function which computes the distances between sequences, I have problems with computer's memory.
Some people suggested to aggregate identical sequences, compute the distance and cluster the sequences using weights. 
But this solution is not sufficient since I have 20000 unique sequences in my data.
An other solution proposed in the web is to analyze a sample of the data.
So, I have analyzed a sample of 5000 trajectories in my data.
Is there another solution by using all the trajectories ?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Christelle FERREIRA

Comment: Hello, Christelle, and welcome to the site!  I have to say, though, that your question, being about trouble with a specific R package rather than about a statistics problem as such, would probably get a faster answer over on stackoverflow, where I notice quite a few questions with the 'traminer' tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, but none of the options is perfect.

- Aggregate identical sequences (as proposed), see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929936/problem-with-big-data-during-computation-of-sequence-distances-using-tramine/15929937
- Compute only the lower half of the distance matrix (use the argument `"full.matrix=FALSE"`)
- Reduce the granularity of the sequences, see here [Modifying the time granularity of a state sequence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/modifying-the-time-granularity-of-a-state-sequence/43639) . By using say weeks instead of days, you will lower the number of distinct sequences, and, hence, the impact of proposition 1 (aggregating sequence).
- Use a computer with more RAM.